# Gracefully fail ansible to maintain idempotency when user loses access as part of a playbook

Tags: configuration, ansible, devops

I am working on two Ansible roles: one to bootstrap a system, another to update the OS and reboot.

These roles are being launched by the `master.yml` file:

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  roles:
  - rh_bootstrap

- hosts: all
  remote_user: devops
  become: true
  roles:
  - os_update
...
```

The bootstrap role installs a necessary package for selinux, adds a devops user, copies an ssh key, and hardens ssh.

```
---
- name: Ensure that libselinux is installed
  yum:
    name: libselinux-python
    state: installed

- name: Create devops user
  user:
    name: devops
    state: present
    comment: Create devops user

- name: Install SSH key for devops user
  authorized_key:
    user: devops
    key: "ssh-rsa MYKEYHERE"
    state: present

- name: Make sure devops user is sudoer with no pw requirements
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/sudoers
    state: present
    regexp: '^devops ALL\='
    line: 'devops ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL'
    validate: 'visudo -cf %s'

- name: Ensure SELinux is Enforcing
  selinux:
    policy: targeted
    state: enforcing

- name: Disable empty password login
  lineinfile: dest={{ sshd_config }} regexp="^#?PermitEmptyPasswords" line="PermitEmptyPasswords no"
  notify: restart sshd

- name: Disable root SSH login
  lineinfile: dest={{ sshd_config }} regexp="^#?PermitRootLogin" line="PermitRootLogin no"
  notify: restart sshd

- name: Disable password login
  lineinfile: dest={{ sshd_config }} regexp="^#?PasswordAuthentication" line="PasswordAuthentication no"
  notify: restart sshd
...
```

At this point, master.yml switches to the devops user. The devops user has a key defined in my **ansible.cfg** defaults.

The problem is that if I attempt to rerun `master.yml`, the root user can no longer connect into the host because I've disabled root login completely, so it errors out. Is there any graceful way to handle a user failing to be able to login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: false
  pre_tasks:
    - block:
        - wait_for_connection:
            timeout: 5
      rescue:
        - meta: clear_host_errors
        - meta: end_play
  roles:
    - rh_bootstrap

- hosts: all
  remote_user: devops
  become: true
  roles:
    - os_update
```

In short:

- you need to prevent fact-gathering which happenes before any other processing in a play (and would cause the first one to fail if `root` was blocked);
- in pre_tasks section check connectivity (fail with a small timeout as time doesn’t matter here — the expected situation is binary — either it can connect or not);
- execute the above task in a block-rescue section and stop processing the play if (expected) connection failure occurred;
- continue the first play and apply `rh_bootstrap` role otherwise.

---

Sidenotes:

- Don't use `lineinfile` use `template`.
- I would consider it a design flaw not to "re-run" `rh_bootstrap` role later on.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - I will give this approach a shot later tonight when I get home from work. 

I hadn't thought of using templates rather than lineinfile, but that definitely makes sense. 

Any ideas about how to make rh_bootstrap "re-runnable" later? The intention is taking a new greenfield host, log in as root, set up a non-root CM user, and then locking out root since it is considered a bad practice to allow root login. By nature of the work done, I'm not sure how I could make it something that could be run twice.

Comment: I can't see any task in the `rh_bootstrap` that cannot be used in later runs. Just do it.

Comment: You can't connect as the root user on later runs if the play disables root connections. So trying to run it again causes SSH connectivity failures (unless I'm misunderstanding you).

Comment: And who says you need to run `rh_bootstrap` only when connected with `root` account?